# Cannot set session variables

Tags: php, session

I've been looking at other examples for the past three days, checking documentation, etc. All I want to do is set session variables to user info after login. All my connections are fine because I can stay logged in and return the session variable of my username easy. The other info doesn't work. I feel like it's probably something really stupid.

Here is my code:

```
$user_data = array(); 

$get_user_data = "SELECT 
  user_id
, user_level
, user_type
FROM users 
WHERE user_name = :user_name";
$query = $pdo->prepare($get_user_data);
$query->bindParam(":user_name", $username); 
$query->execute();     
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $user_id =$row['user_id'];
    $user_level =$row['user_level'];
    $user_type =$row['user_type'];

//do something with the variables
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
    $_SESSION['user_type'] = $user_type;

// var_dump inside the brackets here returns the variable values fine

}

// var_dump outside the brackets here returns the variables as NULL
```

This is the full code for the page:

```
<?php 
session_start();

    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

//include config
require_once('includes/config.php');
//include header template
require('includes/header.php');

//check if already logged in move to home page
if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ 
    echo '<div id="errors">You are already logged in. </div>'; 

} 

//process login form if submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $username = $_POST['user_name'];
    $password = $_POST['user_password'];

    if($user->login($username,$password)){ 
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $username; // set session variable of username to that of logged in user

    $user_data = array(); 

    $get_user_data = "SELECT 
      user_id
    , user_level
    , user_type
    FROM users 
    WHERE user_name = :user_name";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($get_user_data);
    $query->bindParam(":user_name", $username); 
    $query->execute();     
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $user_id =$row['user_id'];
        $user_level =$row['user_level'];
        $user_type =$row['user_type'];

    //do something with the variables
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
        $_SESSION['user_type'] = $user_type;

    // var_dump inside the brackets here returns the variable values fine

    }

    // var_dump outside the brackets here returns the variables as NULL

        // ordinarily I redirect the user, but for testing this is turned off. 
        //header('Location: chapter.php');
        //exit;

    } else {
        $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';
    }

}//end if submit

//define page title
$title = 'Login'; 
?>
<div id = "wrapper">
            <div id = "errors">
            <?php         
            var_dump($row['user_id']);
            var_dump($row['user_level']);
            var_dump($row['user_type']);
            var_dump($_SESSION['user_name']);
            ?></div>
            <form role="form" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
                <?php
                //check for any errors
                if(isset($error)){
                    foreach($error as $error){
                        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$error.'</p>';
                    }
                }

                if(isset($_GET['action'])){

                    //check the action
                    switch ($_GET['action']) {
                        case 'active':
                            echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Your account is now active you may now log in.</h2>";
                            break;
                        case 'reset':
                            echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Please check your inbox for a reset link.</h2>";
                            break;
                        case 'resetAccount':
                            echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Password changed, you may now login.</h2>";
                            break;
                    }

                }


                ?>

                <div id = "form-section">
                    <div id = "form-header"><img src="img/ds-icon20px.png"> Log in.</div><HR SIZE = "1" WIDTH="100%" NOSHADE>
                    <small>Username: </small><br />
                    <input type="text" name="user_name" id="username" placeholder="User Name" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['user_name']; } ?>" tabindex="1">
                    <small>Password: </small><br />
                    <input type="password" name="user_password" id="password" placeholder="Password" tabindex="2">
                    <br /><br />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" tabindex="3"> <a href='reset.php'>Forgot your Password?</a>
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
<?php 
//include footer template
require('includes/footer.php'); 
?>
```

Comment: Add `session_start()` at the top of your code.

Comment: That's only part of my code. I didn't want to post the whole page because the problem seems to lie with just the portion that calls the db. I've added the code to the whole page below my first section, though.

Comment: ignoring the sessions for a second.  If you declare a variable before your while loop   like `$testdata='beforewhile';   `    then set that to $user_id.  Does it exist after the while?

Comment: PHP doesn't have a block-level scope so the `while` loop brackets are irrelevant. What are you actually dumping with `var_dump()`? What happens if your query doesn't return a row?

Comment: The $_SESSION['user_name'] = $username; works all throughout my site while I'm logged in. But I did as you suggested and it's returning null. Here's where I put the testdata you suggested.  `code if($user->login($username,$password)){ 
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $username; // set session variable of username to that of logged in user
        $testdata= 'beforewhile';
        $user_id = $testdata;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, didn't fit in a comment

ignoring the sessions for a second. If you declare a variable before your while loop like $testdata='beforewhile'; then set that to $user_id. Does it exist after the while?

```
$testdata='beforewhile';
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo 'FIRST '.$testdata;
    $user_id =$row['user_id'];
    $user_level =$row['user_level'];
    $user_type =$row['user_type'];

//do something with the variables
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
    $_SESSION['user_type'] = $user_type;
$testdata=$user_id;
// var_dump inside the brackets here returns the variable values fine
echo 'LAST '.$testdata;
}
echo 'after '.$testdata;
```

Comment: It exists after the while loop but now it has user_id in it...so what's the question mean?

Comment: I mean you may have some amazing point here...but its not obvious to me what you're getting at.

Comment: The session stores the user_name just fine, but if I put the testdata before the while loop and set it to user_id, it returns NULL.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your new code. Now it returns this: `code FIRST beforewhileLAST 14after 14 `

Comment: @JandenHale Oh. Because you have a null userid coming out of that query. You do realize you're trying to put many different userids in the same session variable, right?  That's awful.  Don't do that.

Comment: For clarification, my user_id number is 14.

Comment: @developerwjk, that makes sense. I'm trying to save the user data for the logged in user so I can access it for various things like making posts, checking permission levels, etc. I can't figure it out. And I thought the code is only putting the user_id of WHERE user_name = $username into the session variable.

Comment: @JandenHale You need SQL to return only ONE row, and then use `if` not `while`.

Comment: @JandenHale Since you are already specifying the username in the where clause of the SQL, and yet its returning multiple rows, it means your table is messed up. You need to set username to have a `unique` constraint on the table so you don't get duplicates of the same username which you apparently have(?)

Comment: Isn't the WHERE user_name = :user_name"; going to return only one row?

Comment: I wanted to see if you were getting a row for the userdata you were looking for and also a null row that was resetting your variables.  From your reply earlier, I only saw one LAST which means only one row.  Add ' LIMIT 1' to the end of your Query to limit it to only one result and/or switch your `while` to an `if`

Comment: I have only three users in my database, and in the registration page, it checks to see if a username already exists to prevent duplicates.

Comment: That's it, guys. The if statement and the limit 1 is what got it to work. Sorry if I am difficult, I'm trying to wrap my head around everything. I've only been doing php for a few weeks and I'm trying to cobble together all this website.

Comment: Great.  It looks like you were getting a null row and overwriting your own variables from the $row['user_id'] variables.  The `if` and `limit 1` both kept you with only one row.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables only exists inside `while` loop, try defining them outside and before loop.

You are setting the value of each variable multiple times, I think you need to use an array to store all rows:

```
$rowList = array();
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $rowList[] = $row;
}
```

Then you can show values like this:

```
 echo $rowList[0]['user_id'];
 echo $rowList[0]['user_level'];
```

If your query returns only one row you can use `if` instead of `while`:

```
$user_id = null;
$user_level = null;
$user_type = null;
if($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $user_id =$row['user_id'];
    $user_level =$row['user_level'];
    $user_type =$row['user_type'];

    //do something with the variables
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
    $_SESSION['user_type'] = $user_type;
}

var_dump($user_id);
var_dump($user_level);
var_dump($user_type);
```